# How to serialize / deserialize deeply nested nodes with YamlDotNet?

Tags: c#, mongodb, yaml, yamldotnet

I'm trying to create / read a MongoDB configuration file through C#.

The format is YAML and some nodes are deeply nested like this:

```
storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB : 5
```

From the getting started documentation, I figured I should create new classes for `storage`, `wiredTiger`, `engineConfig` which will ultimately hold a single property, `cacheSizeGB`. I feel like I'm writing more boilerplate classes just to define the class hierarchy.

Is there a simpler way that requires less class definitions?

Comment: Wouldn't "storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB" be a single key? Is it actually nested?

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm new to YAML, I'm not sure of the difference. `storage`, `wiredTiger` and `engineConfig` have multiple other entries. In the sample files, all those keywords are separated on multiple lines with increasing indentation.